# Java, Kryo: Add fields to class persisted as FieldSerializer

Tags: java, serialization, kryo

This is using the Kryo serialization library.

I've got objects already serialized to the DB with `FieldSerializer`. Now, I'd like to add a couple fields to the serialized classs, and obtain backward compatibility with them.

Is this possible?  What is the best way to do it?

I tried just switching the deserializer to `TaggedFieldSerializer`, but not surprisingly, that doesn't work (`Encountered unregistered class ID:`).

So is there a way to deserialize these objects using the same class with the additional fields?

---

**Update 1**

In case its not obvious, I want to avoid deleting all the previously serialized objects from the DB.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways that come to mind (depending on whether they can all be held in the JVM process memory at one time). You will however have to go through this process before new fields are added:

If you can hold them all in memory:

- Read them all in via a Kryo instance that uses a `FieldSerializer`, then write them all out via a different Kryo instance that supports backwards compatibility. Even if you don't have enough RAM, you could consider temporarily increasing the size of configured virtual memory just for this exercise and increasing the VM heap size, though the processing will be slower if a large amount of swapping is needed.

If you cannot hold them all in memory:

- Read them in one at a time via a Kryo instance that uses a   `FieldSerializer`, then write them out one at a time via a different Kryo instance that supports backwards compatibility, to a different table with the same schema, or a different database instance with the same database schema as the input (if it is easier to do this at the databse level).

As to the choice of new `Serializer`, `CompatibleFieldSerializer` would be the easiest, because the serialization changeover can initially be performed without any POJO field changes. Then you could make your required changes against the newly CompatibleFieldSerializer serialized objects. Alternately (I have not tried this), you could try annotating the fields as per the `TaggedFieldSerializer` requirements, and follow the same steps - it should work, as long as the FieldSerializer ignores the annotations used by `TaggedFieldSerializer` while reading in the objects.

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid it’s not possible. From [FieldSerializer’s Javadocs, L55-56](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo/blob/master/src/com/esotericsoftware/kryo/serializers/FieldSerializer.java):

> It does not support adding, removing, or changing the type of fields
>   without invalidating previously serialized bytes.